# Questions about Data Binding in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I heard of something about **Data Binding** early today. Since I wanted to have a try of it and know about it, I created a test project.

**Data Binding** is is a support repository available on API 7+. with **dataBinder**, we are capable of saying goodbye to `findViewById` (which is complained about a lot by developers) when binding application logics and layouts.

Here are information about my project:
**Android Studio:**

- Current version: Android Studio 1.3
- Build number: AI-141.2071668
- Android SDK Tools: 24.3.3
- Android Platform Version: MNC revision 2

**Project `build.gradle`:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta4'
        classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Module `build.gradle`:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-MNC'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.danielpan.databindingsample"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 'MNC'
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

And when I run this project on a Genymotion Emulator(which is Nexus 5 in Android 5.1.0), errors happened:

```
Installing me.danielpan.databindingsample
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/me.danielpan.databindingsample"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/me.danielpan.databindingsample
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]


DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall me.danielpan.databindingsample
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

So, I have some questions:

**1**, `DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR` happened many times. It seems that this error happens when I set 
    compileSdkVersion 'android-MNC'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
So, it's the problem of Android Build Tools of this version?

**2**, I followed [Data Binding Guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html), but I think it's old. Because **Gradle Plugin** has been [1.3.0-beta4](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/), version of **dataBinder** should have evolved since released. So, what's is the latest version of **Data Binding Plugin**?

Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**P.S.**:

When I set version of Gradle Plugin `1.2.3`, `buildToolsVersion` "22.0.1" `compileSdkVersion` 22, and `targetSdkVersion` 22, `DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR` doesn't happen again, Could somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the second question. RC1 was just released, though the documentation has not been updated yet. It will read:

```
dependencies {
   classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta4"
   classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"
}
```